# cx_oracle does not work in a given conda environment but does in another one

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, macos, cx-oracle

I am using cx_oracle to access an Oracle database using Python 3. I have several environments, and they are managed with Conda. In one of them (base), I can query the database, in another one I can't... Both environment have the same cx_oracle version but only the second one gives:

> DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help

Before I start to change my oracle set up, I would like to understand what is happening.

Thanks

Comment: are you using mac catalina ??

Comment: since this morning yes but I noticed this error before

Comment: which version of cx_oracle and which version of instant_client ??

Comment: @RobertoHernandez cx_oracle=7.0.0 and instantclient_11_2

Comment: I know there are some issues with catalina and some instant clients. Did you try to use cx_oracle 8.0.0 and oracle 12.2 instant client. That configuration I know works for macos catalina , it does not for oracle instant client 18 and 19 for some users.

Comment: Thanks @RobertoHernandez, without touching the instant client I created a new conda env and I can access my db from there. The point of my question is really to understand why with the same conda install, one env has an issue with cx_oracle but not the other.

Comment: good for you! ;)  One thing I don't understand is why they don't release an oracle client version ( not the instant client ) for mac os. I have never been a fan of the instant client version, I know that for some scenarios is ok, but for many other it is not enough.